# I want to replace Normal Join in Informatica by Cross join in SQL by running a query in source qualifier?

Tags: sql, join, transformation, informatica

Normal join in informatica has been done using Dummy fields added in table dev and remote. Columns in dev table are database_region,site_cd, dev_nm,
dev_locn_id, dev_typ, bond_ind , FRM_ID, AP_ID ,DUMMY_DEV
and Columns of remote are node_id and DUMMY_REMOTE.
We are creating a cross join using condition DUMMY_DEV = DUMMY_REMOTE declaring Master Columns as node_id and DUMMY_REMOTE. 
However, as per client requirement we have create the Cross Join in sql. TO achieve that i am running a cross join using SQL query. When i compared the Row count and data between the Normal Join of Informatica and Cross Join of SQL, It resulted perfectly same. However the order of rows are different.
Can anyone suggest how can i achieve the exact same result?
Below is the query i am using.

```
select database_region,site_cd,dev_nm,
dev_locn_id, dev_typ, bond_ind , FRM_ID, AP_ID ,
node_id
from dev  cross join 
remote   ;
```

XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
Result from Informatica Normal Join

```
01  AGSTAR      AGSTARXAHA1-AGST        AUGUSTA/80MVC7B/N65     C7 /M           Y   01                          20MEG
01  AGSTAR      AGSTARXAHA1-AGST        AUGUSTA/80MVC7B/N65     C7 /M           Y   01                          20MEG
01  AGSTAR      AGSTARXAHA1-AGST        AUGUSTA/80MVC7B/N65     C7 /M           Y   01                          20MEG
01  AGSTAR      AGSTARXAHA1-AGST        AUGUSTA/80MVC7B/N65     C7 /M           Y   01                          20MEG
```

XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx
Result of Cross Join from informatica

```
01  AGSTAR      AGSTARXAHA1-AGST        AUGUSTA/80MVC7B/N65     C7 /M           Y   01                          15MEG
01  AGSTAR      AGSTARXAHA1-AGST        AUGUSTA/80MVC7B/N65     C7 /M           Y   01                          15MEG
01  AGSTAR      AGSTARXAHA1-AGST        AUGUSTA/80MVC7B/N65     C7 /M           Y   01                          15MEG
01  AGSTAR      AGSTARXAHA1-AGST        AUGUSTA/80MVC7B/N65     C7 /M           Y   01                          20MEG
```

For Demonstration providing Four output rows, as Cross join results in creation of 100 000 rows.

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  Result sets -- when there is no `order by` -- similarly represent *unordered* sets.

You can run the same query twice, on the same data, in the same database, and get the rows in a different order.  SQL does not care.

If you want the results in a particular order, then use `order by`.  If you want the results to always be returned in the same order, then use `order by`.

Comment: Thanks Gordon for Reply, Let me try with order by then will share the results here.

Comment: I didn't get the right result with order by clause even. Can anyone suggest any other alternative.